# Excel secondary sorting doesn't work. Any work around manually or with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in four columns and i need data first to be sorted by column "A and then by Column "C". When i use sorting at multi level still the column "C" didn't get sorted (Column C has dates). Any help to do it manually or with macro is much appreciated.

I tried all ways, formatting is good, no extra spaces, no formulas...etc

Comment: If dates don't get sorted chronologically, chances are high that they are not really dates. Please upload a data sample. Best would be an actual Excel file, so we can see the data types in the cells. Upload to an ad-free file sharing service like Dropbox or OneDrive, share the file and post a link. Post that link into your question, not a comment. then leave a comment to alert the people who are following this question.

Comment: Thanks. I got this problem sorted. Actually the problem is not with dates, the problem is with another column where it has data such as BIM-0000078-2019.